# HTML5 and CSS3 Intellisense in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html, css, intellisense

I tried installing extension from extension manager but no use. Can you help how to install IntelliSense for HTML 5 and CSS 3 in visual studio 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install `SP1` you will get intellisense for HTML5 & CSS3. The entire HTML5 specification isn’t supported but most of the new elements and attributes are

Answer (score 2):

you can download the **CSS 3 Intellisense Schema** from the visual studio gallery

Version 2.0:

13 Visual Studio 2010 Languge Suppurt.
-moz-, -webkit- and -o- Browsers Suppurt.
CSS 3 In Html 5 & Style Tag Suppurt.
if install visual studio 2010 sp1. in aspx, html, master and other file when use style tag or style attibute,  CSS3 Intellisense shown. please first install visual studio 2010 sp1 then install CSS3 IS 2.0.

CSS3 Set at Default Validation

Transform Properties
Other CSS3 properties.